# accessing object created from custom class

Tags: c#, class, object

I think the problem I am having is related to my understanding of classes and objects.

The question has two parts.

1. Why cant I see the object car1 to set a text box = to the value of the car1.name.
2. How do I access the car1 object from any button or method later in my code.

   ```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Cars car1 = new Cars();
       car1.Name = "Chevy";

   }

   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

      TextBox1.Text = car1.Name.ToString();

   }
   ```

`car1.Name.ToString();` is not visible from the button action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring the `car1` variable within the `Page_Load` method, making it only visible to that method.

You need to make it into a field - declaring it *outside* of all methods.

```
Cars car1;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    car1 = new Cars();
    car1.Name = "Chevy";
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TextBox1.Text = car1.Name.ToString();
}
```

When done this way, you need to take care to only call methods on `car1` after initializing it (i.e. first line of `Page_Load` in my example), otherwise you will get a `NullReferenceException`.

An alternative that can avoid the possible exception is to initialize during declaration, as you have done in your example (only as a field instead of a method variable):

```
Cars car1 = new Cars();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    car1.Name = "Chevy";
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TextBox1.Text = car1.Name.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest putting Car into a property in the class, and utilizing viewstate.

```
public Cars Car {
get {
    return (Cars) ViewState["Car"];
}
set {
    ViewState["Car"] = value;
}
}
```

Comment: This seems needlessly complicated. Why would the OP use viewstate here? And why serialize the object back and forth to viewstate on every reference to it?